# Using variable before initialization. JS

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Recently I found this piece of code and this is a "find what is wrong and modify" type of exercise. The purpose is to make this code work without moving the message variable on top of the code and I am pretty curious how I can achieve that.

```
function myMethod(cb) {
    cb();
}

myMethod( () => console.log(message) );

const message = "My message";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing came to my mind was to declare variable with `var` keyword, then program won't throw error but still doesn't print the message. you could never carry the initilization to the top of the file without using [event loop](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%27s%20event%20loop%20in%20js&oq=what%27s%20event%20loop%20in%20js&aqs=chrome..69i57.4467j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Appareantly only way would be surrounding `myMethod( () => console.log(message) )` 
inside a setTimeout function

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  myMethod( () => console.log(message) )
}, 0)
```

This way the execution of function will be delayed until call stack is empty. Then it'll execute the function with the current value which will be set by then.

Comment: Yes, true. Just realized and came back here to post the answer myself and I'm glad to see that I already got some answers.

Comment: Or the callback execution inside the "myMethod" function can be wrapped in a setTImeout, eg; function myMethod( cb ) { setTimeout( cb, 0 ) }

Answer (score 0):

Redeclare `const message` as `var message`. This will hoist the variable to the top of the scope. Here is a good article about this behaviour:
https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javascript-hoisting-var-let-const-variables/

Comment: If you try that, you will see undefined will be printed, The declarations are moved to the top not the initializations.